# Text drawn in HTML canvas has edges

Tags: html, canvas

I draw the text "Hello World" inside that text a couple of times inside a 'Canvas' in HTML5. The outmost text is red, next is yellow, inside green the text, and the most inner text is blue.

What can I do about the sharp edges I see on the letter W?

How can I make the text render smoothly?

```
<canvas id="Can" width="1200" height="500" dir="ltr">
                <script>
                    var can = document.getElementById("Can");
                    var context = can.getContext("2d");
                    context.font = "200px Arial";
                    context.lineWidth = 40;
                    context.strokeStyle = "red";
                    context.strokeText("Hello World", 25, 200);
                    context.lineWidth = 30;
                    context.strokeStyle = "yellow";
                    context.strokeText("Hello World", 25, 200);
                    context.lineWidth = 10;
                    context.strokeStyle = "LightGreen";
                    context.strokeText("Hello World", 25, 200);
                    context.fillStyle = "blue";
                    context.fillText("Hello World", 25, 200);
                </script>
                </canvas>
```

[image: This is how the text is shown on my screen]

Comment: You can prevent this effect by setting the context.lineJoin to either 'round' or 'bevel' (it defaults to 'miter'). It fixes the issue but as you'll see, it completely changes the final aspect of the text.

Comment: Thanks for your help! What if I don't want rounded text or beveled? How come the letter H is OK and only letters like V or W make this problem?

Comment: You're welcome. Issue is a 'line' with such width is more properly described as a rectangle, and joining two rects together properly while respecting the 'miter' constraint is difficult. H has only 90 degrees angle -easy-, but V, W among other have like less than 30 degree angles, so canvas trades accuracy for speed -with reason- and fails here. The font size / lineWidth ratio (==5) is just too low for this way of proceeding. I see no solution that wouldn't require to go into each glyphs (... :-O ...), sorry. Maybe someone will !

Answer (score 0):

i am not an expert sorry i cannot explain why and i can tell it was linewidth which was doing this to W

i did this which made it smoother

```
<canvas id="Can" width="1200" height="500" dir="ltr">
                <script>
                    var can = document.getElementById("Can");
                    // Used for clearing the canvas
                    can.width = can.width;
                    var context = can.getContext("2d");
                    context.font = "220px Arial";
                    context.lineWidth = 11;
                    context.strokeStyle = "red";
                    context.strokeText("Hello World", 25, 202);
                    context.lineWidth = 10;
                    context.strokeStyle = "yellow";
                    context.strokeText("Hello World", 25, 202);
                    context.lineWidth = 4;
                    context.strokeStyle = "LightGreen";
                    context.strokeText("Hello World", 25, 200);
                    context.fillStyle = "blue";
                    context.fillText("Hello World", 25, 200);
                </script>
                </canvas>
```

live demo 
http://jsfiddle.net/maree_chaudhry/wMSfB/1/

i know the look is nt the same still it is smooth now if you find better way to solve it please do share with me :)

Comment: It still doens't answer the question and the problem is shown in your link as well. You made the edge thinner by reducing the lindWidth, yet you haven't removed it completly.